# Button to increase an DIV number variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amcharts

I have 8 of the following charts

https://jsfiddle.net/BernydotJAr/grwzfjsn/

each with different DIV ID of course and I have tried to put a button in the middle of it to switch or change between them like a slide show, I was able to change images but not DIVS.

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>               
<div id="chartdiv2"></div>
```

I have tried with Jquery but I can't display what's inside the div. so when i click a button it should add a number like chartdiv & 1, chartdiv & 2 and so on, so I can display one by one. Below is the jquery code  ( I got it from here: http://www.html5marketplace.com/slideshow/direct/index.html)

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    var pages = $('#container li'), current=0;
    var currentPage,nextPage;
    var handler=function(){
        $('#container .button').unbind('click');
        currentPage= pages.eq(current);
        if($(this).hasClass('prevButton'))
        {
            if (current <= 0)
                current=pages.length-1;
            else
                current=current-1;
            nextPage = pages.eq(current);   

            nextPage.css("marginLeft",-604);
            nextPage.show();
            nextPage.animate({ marginLeft: 0 }, 800,function(){
                currentPage.hide();
            });
            currentPage.animate({ marginLeft: 604 }, 800,function(){
                $('#container .button').bind('click',handler);
            });
        }
        else
        {

            if (current >= pages.length-1)
                current=0;
            else
                current=current+1;
            nextPage = pages.eq(current);   

            nextPage.css("marginLeft",604);
            nextPage.show();
            nextPage.animate({ marginLeft: 0 }, 800,function(){
            });
            currentPage.animate({ marginLeft: -604 }, 800,function(){
                currentPage.hide();
                $('#container .button').bind('click',handler);
            });
        }
    }

    $('#container .button').click(handler);

   });

</script>
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle link is incorrect.

Comment: Please update you fiddle, it does not work

Comment: Fixed, thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided and the code you got from the other site the divs must be inside li elements.Something like this

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li>
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>         
</li>
<li style="display:none;">
  <div id="chartdiv2"></div>            
</li>
<li style="display:none;">
  <div id="chartdiv3"></div>            
</li>
</ul>
<span class="button prevButton"></span>
<span class="button nextButton"></span>
</div>
```

See full code here

https://jsfiddle.net/grwzfjsn/3/

Comment: OMG, yeah that makes sense...  thank you so much, this is what I wanted. I don't know how I can thank you but yeah... I'm so happy.

Comment: Glad I helped you :)